# Failed to build Flutter with `Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh: Permission denied` error

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, build, codemagic

Im traing to build a flutter APP to iOS using a codemagic or Macbook, but I have a problem. I use this commads to create a build.
It appears we are not doing clean builds of flutter/engine. The old header files
I wanna create a building to iOS.
I use this commads

```
 flutter build ios
```

and return this.

```
== Building for iOS ==


> /usr/local/bin/flutter build ios --debug --no-codesign

Warning: Building for device with codesigning disabled. You will have to manually codesign before deploying to device.

Building com.coachingconcurseiros.app for device (ios)...
Upgrading project.pbxproj

Project base configurations detected, removing.

Running pod install...                                          
    6.4s
Warning: Podfile is out of date
  This can cause issues if your application depends on plugins that do not support iOS.
  See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#plugin-platforms for details.
  If you have local Podfile edits you would like to keep, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45197 for instructions.
To regenerate the Podfile, run:
  rm ios/Podfile

Running Xcode build...                                          

Xcode build done.                                           137.1s

Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterChannels.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    #import "Headers/Flutter.h"
    ^
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterCodecs.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterPlatformViews.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterMacros.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterHeadlessDartRunner.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterAppDelegate.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterBinaryMessenger.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterViewController.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterEngine.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterCallbackCache.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterPlugin.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterPluginAppLifeCycleDelegate.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._Flutter.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterDartProject.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterTexture.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    15 warnings generated.
    15 warnings generated.
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterChannels.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    #import "Headers/Flutter.h"
    ^
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterCodecs.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterPlatformViews.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterMacros.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterHeadlessDartRunner.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterAppDelegate.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterBinaryMessenger.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterViewController.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterEngine.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterCallbackCache.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterPlugin.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterPluginAppLifeCycleDelegate.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._Flutter.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterDartProject.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'Flutter' does not include header '._FlutterTexture.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    15 warnings generated.
    15 warnings generated.
    /Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_statusbarcolor-0.2.3/ios/Classes/FlutterStatusbarcolorPlugin.m:15:37: warning: implicit conversion from 'long long' to 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') changes value from 38482458385 to -172247279 [-Wconstant-conversion]
    static NSInteger statusBarViewTag = 38482458385;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning generated.
    2020-11-11 16:47:42.499 ibtoold[2946:57064] DEBUG: Added to environment: {
        TMPDIR = "/var/folders/pj/2d8_b7sn6f37c48z4jj09xk80000gn/T/DAC2F8A2-259D-436E-B8E9-0EAA75711902";
    }
    /* com.apple.actool.document.warnings */
    /Users/builder/clone/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/(null)[2d][Icon-App-50x50@1x.png]: warning: The app icon set "AppIcon" has 6 unassigned children.
    /Users/builder/clone/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/(null)[2d][Icon-App-50x50@1x.png]: warning: The app icon set "AppIcon" has 6 unassigned children.
    /* com.apple.actool.document.notices */
    /Users/builder/clone/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[][ipad][76x76][][][1x][][]: notice: 76x76@1x app icons only apply to iPad apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 10.0.
    /* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
    /Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist
    /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon20x20@2x.png
    /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon20x20@2x~ipad.png
    /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon20x20@3x.png
    /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon20x20~ipad.png
    /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon29x29.png
    /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon29x29@2x.png
    /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon29x29@2x~ipad.png
    /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon29x29@3x.png
    /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon29x29~ipad.png
    /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon40x40@2x.png
    /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon40x40@2x~ipad.png
    /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon40x40@3x.png
    /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon40x40~ipad.png
    /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon60x60@2x.png
    /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon60x60@3x.png
    /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png
    /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon76x76~ipad.png
    /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon83.5x83.5@2x~ipad.png
    /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Assets.car

    /Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-46700B3D58DF788A9BC098CC.sh: line 2: /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh: Permission denied
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constru

cting build description
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'Reachability' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'sqflite' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'shared_preferences' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'share' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'path_provider' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'flutter_statusbarcolor' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'connectivity' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'connectivity_macos' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'shared_preferences_windows' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'shared_preferences_web' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'shared_preferences_macos' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'connectivity_for_web' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'shared_preferences_linux' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'path_provider_windows' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'path_provider_linux' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'path_provider_macos' from project 'Pods')

Encountered error while building for device.

Build failed :|
Failed to build for iOS
```

this is return when I tri to build

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `pod install` in the main project directory where your Podfile is located.

And to build it with Codemagic you need to add `pre-build` script

Comment: Thanks. But it does not work. this with the same error